# Java - Cant get it to work

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, java.util.scanner

I have been trying to finish this for a couple of hours now. My program is supposed to generate random numbers due to the users input. Then the program divide the numbers in two new even and odd arrays. I have solved the "generated random numbers" part but now i need too transfer the even and odd numbers into two new arrays.

This is what the output should look like:

```
How many random numbers between 0 - 999 do you want? **12**

Here are the random numbers:
145 538 56 241 954 194 681 42 876 323 2 87

These 7 numbers are even:
538 56 954 194 42 876 2

These 5 numbers are odd:
145 241 681 323 87
```

This is my code at the moment:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SlumpadeTal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hur många slumptal i intervallet 0 - 999 önskas?");
    int antal = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Här är de slumpade talen:");

    int[] arrayen = new int[antal];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayen.length; i++) {
        arrayen[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);

        System.out.print(arrayen[i] + " ");
        if ((arrayen[i] % 2) == 0) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE that i can't use any class for this. such as Arraylist, Vector or others!

Comment: Do you have some code that tries to separate the even and odd numbers?  Please post it.

Comment: little suggestion (I know it doesnt really have anything to do with this quesiton, but I want to say it anyway): try keep your code (variable names and such) English, it makes sharing code much easier. Also, for myself, I am not a native English person, but I find it way easier to program in English, since half of it will be English anyway because of syntax, language keywords, existing libraries and such

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to count to number of even numbers and odd numbers,
create arrays of those sizes, and once again iterate over your original array to put each number in it's place.

edit: something like this:

```
int evenCounter = 0;
int oddCounter = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Hur många slumptal i intervallet 0 - 999 önskas?");
int antal = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Här är de slumpade talen:");

int[] arrayen = new int[antal];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayen.length; i++) {
    arrayen[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);

    System.out.print(arrayen[i] + " ");
    if ((arrayen[i] % 2) == 0) {
         evenCounter++;
        }
    else
         oddCounter++;
    }
}
int[] evenArray = new int[evenCounter];
int[] oddArray = new int[oddCounter];
evenCounter = 0;
oddCounter = 0;
for (int i =0; i < arrayen.length; i++){
    if ((arrayen[i] % 2) == 0) {
         evenArray[evenCounter] = arrayen[i];
         evenCounter++;
        }
    else{
         oddArray[oddCounter] = arrayen[i];
         oddCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use ArrayList or Vector to not iterate once again over the array, but this is usually less efficient

Comment: But if the user wants 100 random numbers? How do i put the even and odd numbers in two separate arrays? The modulus "arrayen[i] == 0" sorts out the even numbers, but how do i save those numbers into a new array? I'm lost :(

Comment: Look again at the code and try to understqand what's happening after the first for loop. New arrays are being created to hold even numbers and odd numbers. As said in other answers - you can use ArrayList to avoid this second loop. I usually try to stay away from dynamic length data structures if possible.

Comment: U are the best! I edited my text, I can't use any class, such as ArrayList, vector etc.

Comment: Sorry to bother.. But it doesn't seem to work. The output is "[I@135fbaa4" several of times. Cant seem to get the Strings "These 7 numbers are even:" and "These 5 numbers are odd:" in the right spot either. I really appreciate your help @user3445972

Comment: Given the restriction of not using a Collection class I think this is the best and simplest solution. A better solution that only takes one pass is to create two arrays of the specified size, fill them when the numbers are generated and then use System.arraycopy to "trim" them each down to the appropriate size at the end.

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be divide the number into odd or even number after a number is generated. Using `arraylist` will be better than array because its capacity will be grow automatically and it is suitable for your case because you dont know how many even number or odd number will be generate for each time.

Comment: dammit, you beat me by 9 seconds :( :P

Comment: That show `arraylist` should be more suitable for this case. :)

Answer (score 0):

The if-statement you have in your code (`if ((arrayen[i] % 2) == 0)`) is correct.

What I suggest doing is instead of creating new arrays, create a collection type that has a dynamic length, such as an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). That way you don't have to worry about figuring out the size first, and thus don't have to iterate twice.

If you really need an array for whatever reason, you can always convert the ArrayList to an array with [ArrayList#toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[]))